gfortran: Error: Interface of ‘rfunct’ at (1) must be explicit
I am getting following error while compiling Fortran code using gfortran
Error: Interface of ‘rfunct’ at (1) must be explicit
Interface is defined as part of a module like this.
 interface
    subroutine ifunct(rfunct)  bind(c)
      import :: c_double
      real (kind=c_double), external, bind(c) :: rfunct
    end subroutine
  end interface

Here, rfunct is a function pointer passed by calling routine. for example.,
call setvalue(rang)

Here, rang is the actual function that is being called and is defined as public in a separate module and returns real(R8) value.
I have tried compiling this code with multiple compilers. With g95, this compiles successfully. I am trying to do the same using gfortran as g95 is not actively maintained.

@francescalus rfunct is not an actual function. it is just a placeholder for actual function which is rang in this case. Do I need to define interface for rfunct. If yes, how to do so.
Also, why is it that g95 compiles it successfully and not the gfortran.

Within ifunct rfunct is an actual function: it's a dummy procedure. It's associated with rang (as the actual argument) but it's very much a function in its own right.

If you can [edit] to show the definition of rang itself we can advise on how to match things up.

@francescalus rand is defined as part of a module and is used to generate a random number.
Is it possible to define explicit interface for a function when the function itself does not have a body.

There can be another interface block for rfunct in the interface block for ifunct, they would be written in a similar way. If rang is accessible, you can use procedure(rang) instead of your real (kind=c_double), external, bind(c). Be aware that interface and interface block are two different things. Explicit interface does not require an interface block.

When declaring a function, no matter where, it is never allowed to use a form like
real, external, bind(c) :: func

This is an explicit violation of the Fortran standard.1
A function declaration like
real, external :: func

says that func is a function whose function result is of type REAL, and it has an implicit interface.  gfortran's error message is a little off, but is trying to say func has the BIND attribute means func should have an explicit interface.  This is a contradiction.
You need to decide whether func has an implicit or explicit interface.
If you want the dummy procedure rfunct of the question to have an implicit interface you can use the real(kind=..), external :: rfunct form; if you want it to have an explicit interface you'll need to give that interface (using either a procedure statement or an interface block).
As rang (the actual argument procedure) is a public module procedure, it seems plausible to use an explicit interface.

1 In Fortran 2023 it's C803.
